# Node setuid crashes on Docker Apline

Tags: node.js, docker, google-compute-engine, alpine-linux

I'm running Node 6 inside an Alpine 3.7 Docker image.
The following command:

```
node -e "process.setuid(1002)"
```

crashes generating a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.
I've tried with Node 10 but I get the same error.
The 1002 is a valid user. I've tried with several other users with no success.

My docker image runs on a Google Compute Engine instance with a "Container-Optimized OS 66-10452.89.0 stable" default OS (production).

Comment: Have you tried a non alpine image.

Comment: I haven't tryied the nodejs command with a non-apline image... I'll try that. 
What I've tryied is to execute a setuid inside a .c file compiled with gcc and it works even inside an alpine os. So it seems there is something wrong when the nodejs setuid is executed inside alpine...

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am the project lead of Adélie Linux.)

Node.js sets its I/O thread stack size to `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`, which is not enough to handle signals.  musl libc uses signals to implement `setuid` because the Linux kernel syscall has unsafe behaviour in multithreaded software.

Over at [Adélie Linux](https://www.adelielinux.org/), we've [patched Node](https://code.foxkit.us/adelie/packages/blob/753435f2c9dad50fb4449084c2fee5bfc6178c77/user/node/stack-silliness.patch) to ensure this does not cause a crash.

Answer (score -1):

`setuid` inside Docker is tricky. Can't you just start the Node.js process with the right user?

Comment: I need it to start as root because the main module forks a process that needs to be root and then it downgrades to a low-level user. I've been using this in a production environment for several years... I'm trying to move it inside a docker image but I'm unable to downgrade..